# axios post insert failed, duplicate id on web

Tags: reactjs, axios

I making community board about introduce lodging. When add new lodging, I use axios.post and form. First time post after rendering, my console said "insert failed, duplicate id". but after then, post work not error and post in jsonfile. why this is happend? and how i can fixed first time error. Have a nice day.

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        toggleModale()

        axios.get("http://localhost:3001/Home") //this is just for id 
test, not in real program
            .then(Response => {
                setData(Response.data.length)
                console.log("sucsess")
            })
            .catch(Error => console.log(Error))

        const Home = {
            home_spot: e.target.home_spot.value,
            tag: e.target.tag.value,
            home_image: e.target.home_image.value,
            home_name: e.target.home_name.value,
            home_site: e.target.home_site.value,
            home_price: e.target.home_price.value,
            reason: e.target.reason.value,
            home_open: e.target.home_open.checked,
            category: e.target.category.value
        }

        axios.post("http://localhost:3001/Home",
            {
                id: data.length + 1,
                home_spot: Home.home_spot,
                tag: Home.tag,
                home_image: Home.home_image,
                home_name: Home.home_name,
                home_site: Home.home_site,
                home_price: Home.home_price,
                reason: Home.reason,
                home_open: Home.home_open,
                category: Home.category,
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
///localhost:3001/Home is json file with json-server
```